# Get innerHTML after looping getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript

My example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="names">
   <i>Name 1.</i>
</div>

<div class="names">
   <i>Name 2.</i>
</div>

<div class="names">
   <i>Name 3.</i>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change all names" onclick="changeNames()" />
<script>
var changeNames = function() {
   var names = document.getElementsByClassName('names');

   for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      names.item(i).textContent = names.item(i).textContent + ' Changed...'
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is : How to get `<i>` tag inside the class name?

`names.item(i).textContent` doesn't include `<i>` tag.

I've tried this but it's not working: `names.item(i).find('i').textContent`

And `names.item(i)` doesn't support `.innerHTML`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)** to get `i` tag inside div.

```js
var changeNames = function() {
  var names = document.getElementsByClassName('names');

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names.item(i).querySelector('i').textContent += ' Changed...'
      // or
      // names[i].querySelector('i').textContent += ' Changed...'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <i>Name 1.</i>
</div>

<div class="names">
  <i>Name 2.</i>
</div>

<div class="names">
  <i>Name 3.</i>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change all names" onclick="changeNames()" />
```

Comment: @Mr.Wolf : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because that is the html content so use innerHTML

```js
var changeNames = function() {
  var names = document.getElementsByClassName('names');

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i].innerHTML += ' Changed...';
    //another approach is to add a text node than to modify the html content like
    //names[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(' Changed...'))
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <i>Name 1.</i>
</div>

<div class="names">
  <i>Name 2.</i>
</div>

<div class="names">
  <i>Name 3.</i>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change all names" onclick="changeNames()" />
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the OP wants the text to be added inside the `<i>` element.